# Change the shape of points in kendo react scatter chart

Tags: kendo-react-ui

I need to change to color and shape of points/items in the kendo react scatter chart. The default is circles with different colors but I need to change it to shapes of diamond, square, circle and plus.

Can anyone please provide help in this regard.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you check the Kendo help page/forums?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ChartSeriesItem
    type="scatter"
    data={data}
    xField="rainfall"
    yField="windSpeed"
    markers={{
     visible: true,
     type: "triangle",
    }}
 />
```

It can be controlled with the Markers properties type and background

Comment: Thanks, this works fine..

The label colors are coming by default and even if i am changing the colors in the markers = { backgroundcolor : 'green' } . The color in the legend label is coming as the default colors which is not matching with the label color. Any idea how we can fix this?